# Ubuntu 16.04 intel graphic driver install problem

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.

I upgraded intel graphic driver from intel graphic driver software which was automatically installed in Ubuntu.

But when I connect a extra monitor(dual monitor) with VGA or HDMI, monitor doesn't detect signal. Ubuntu detect the monitor but monitor doesn't display the screen.

[image: Ubuntu screenshot]

As you can see from the image, Ubuntu definitely detect the monitor.

But the monitor screen is just dark.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the monitor you are trying to connect is the one in the picture, then looks ok to me.

You can see the desktop wallpaper on the HP monitor, for me there is signal.

That is the same configuration I use when plugging my laptop to my TV via HDMI cable.

You won't see the folders you have on the PC/laptop desktop unless you select the mirror display option.

Same for the launchpad bar, if you want it on both monitor you have to select it from the drop down menu in the corrispondent option.